# Why do we pass the root window's 'window' attribute when creating Toplevel windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning how to create parent and child windows using tkinter with an OOP approach but don't fully understand the reason for passing the parent window's 'window' attribute when creating a Toplevel window. See below...

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Main Window")

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me 1", command = self.Open1)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.button2 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me 2", command = self.Open2)
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.button3 = Button(self.master, text="Close", command = self.Close)
        self.button3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


    def Open1(self):
        second_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window2 = Second(second_window)

    def Open2(self):
        third_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window3 = Third(third_window)

    def Close(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class Second():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.second_window = second_window
        self.master.title("Second Window")

class Third():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Third Window")


root_window = Tk()
root_window.geometry("200x85")
main_window = Main(root_window)
root_window.mainloop()
```

Yet the creation of the two Top level windows could also be written without the parameters... it seems to produce the same result:

```
def Open1(self):
            second_window = Toplevel()
            window2 = Second(second_window)

        def Open2(self):
            third_window = Toplevel()
            window3 = Third(third_window)
```

So why do we often pass this root window's attribute when instantiating a Top level window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All widgets except for the root window require a parent. That is simply how tkinter works. If you don't pass in a parent, the root window is the default.

The zen of python says that explicit is better than implicit. Explicitly passing it in prevents people from having to ask this very question, and makes the code slightly easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. So does this mean that without passing the parent (i.e. leaving it as second_window = Toplevel()) makes second_window another root window and therefore not a child of main_window?

Comment: @samwickins32: no. There can be only one root window. Toplevel windows are not and cannot be a root window. If you don't give a toplevel window a parent, it's parent will be the root window.

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much for your time. So in summary, the reason for passing the attribute when creating Toplevel windows is to explicitly state what window it is a child of?